# Scan ISBN from book cover with Pyzbar and OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, barcode, zbar

Hello I'm having issues while parsing image using Python an CV2 + Pyzbar

[image: Example image]

While using other code I'm able to target the codebar within the image, however when parsing the image with the code below is not able to recognize

```
import cv2
import pyzbar.pyzbar as pyzbar
from pyzbar.wrapper import ZBarSymbol

img_file = 'Cover.jpg'
img = cv2.imread(img_file)

gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
barcodes = pyzbar.decode(gray, [ZBarSymbol.EAN13])

for barcode in barcodes:
    print('{}: {}'.format(barcode.type, barcode.data))
```

Basically I've a bunch of covers that I need to scan but cropping the resolution seems is not good enough for him to recognize them

Comment: the resolution of your barcode is s low to the limit that the bars are touching each other!